# Sencha Touch 2: production build won't open in browser

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I've compiled my project using the 'sencha app build production' command.
When I try to load it in browser I get the following error:

```
Error evaluating http://localhost:8888/RFN/build/production/app.js with message: Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading synchronously via XHR: 'src/form/Panel.js'; please verify that the file exists. XHR status code: 404
```

There definitely is no 'src' folder in my production build. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had to declare 'require Ext.form.Panel' in my app.js file.